# Building project after update to Angular 9 results in error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, npm, migration, angular9

I'm trying to update my project to Angular 9 by following the update.angular.io migration guide. After executing `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli` I get the error "ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when executing `ng build --prod`, while `ng build` is still working. `ng build --aot` is also working.

npm logs give the following output

```
   0 info it worked if it ends with ok
   1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build', '--prod' ]
   2 info using npm@6.14.3
   3 info using node@v10.18.0
   4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
   5 info lifecycle my-project@0.1.0~prebuild: my-project@0.1.0
   6 info lifecycle my-project@0.1.0~build: my-project@0.1.0
   7 verbose lifecycle my-project@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
   8 verbose lifecycle my-project@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/path/to/project/my-project/subproject/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
   9 verbose lifecycle my-project@0.1.0~build: CWD: /path/to/project/my-project/subproject
   10 silly lifecycle my-project@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'ng build --prod' ]
   11 silly lifecycle my-project@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
   12 info lifecycle my-project@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
   13 verbose stack Error: my-project@0.1.0 build: `ng build --prod`
   13 verbose stack Exit status 1
   13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
   13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
   13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
   13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
   13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
   13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
   14 verbose pkgid my-project@0.1.0
   15 verbose cwd /path/to/project/my-project/subproject
   16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
   17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build" "--prod"
   18 verbose node v10.18.0
   19 verbose npm  v6.14.3
   20 error code ELIFECYCLE
   21 error errno 1
   22 error my-project@0.1.0 build: `ng build --prod`
   22 error Exit status 1
   23 error Failed at the my-project@0.1.0 build script.
   23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

To solve the problem i updated npm, which did not help. Also i turned off all angular complier checks by setting

```
       "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
       "strictInjectionParameters": false
```

in tsconfig.json. Which also did not work. Deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and make a new `npm install` also did not solve the problem.

`npm version is 6.14.3`
`node version is 10.18.0`

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are facing this issue in your code ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get any information about where in the code the problem occures. While executing ng build --prod there is no stacktrace and nothing.

Comment: Are you able to update to the newest LTS of NodeJS? I think it's 12.x.x...

Comment: updating to newest version Node does not solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, changing `angular.json` configuration solved the problem.

before i had:

`"optimization": true`

and i changed it to:

`"optimization": { "scripts": true, "styles": false }`

And it is now building in production mode. This is not a real solution, but a workaround. So if anybody knows how to fix the problem and keep the style optimization, i would be grateful if you share it.

Comment: This is definitely a workaround, however, this error is so opaque at least this answer gives me a hint.  Thanks!

Comment: Having the same problem, any new insights? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700724/angular-build-cannot-read-property-split-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment117908348_66700724

Answer (score 1):

Angular 9 ships with Ivy and has default aot enabled. I also faced the problem, I removed any "aot" or "buildOptimizer" setting from angular.json for my build configuration.
Eg: production configuration for prod build. Also make sure u try a npm install after cleaning node_modules, if it dont work at one shot.

May be you are having some dependency that is having optimization problems. This trick should work.

```
 "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
```