# Angular doesnt build due to undefined split exception

Tags: angular-cli

When I try to build my project using ng build, I get the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'split' of undefinedSee "/tmp/ng-6X0bro/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Exception details in the log file:

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/home/ahmet/Qimia/tutorial-projects/expense-manager/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:27:55)
at BuildCommand.initialize (/home/ahmet/Qimia/tutorial-projects/expense-manager/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:71:63)
at async BuildCommand.validateAndRun (/home/ahmet/Qimia/tutorial-projects/expense-manager/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:124:9)
at async Object.runCommand (/home/ahmet/Qimia/tutorial-projects/expense-manager/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:186:24)
at async default_1 (/home/ahmet/Qimia/tutorial-projects/expense-manager/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:54:31)
```

and I opened the node-modules-architect-host-js file where the exception occurs:

```
 /**
 * Resolve a builder. This needs to be a string which will be used in a dynamic `import()`
 * clause. This should throw if no builder can be found. The dynamic import will throw if
 * it is unsupported.
 * @param builderStr The name of the builder to be used.
 * @returns All the info needed for the builder itself.
 */
resolveBuilder(builderStr) {
    const [packageName, builderName] = builderStr.split(':', 2);
    if (!builderName) {
        throw new Error('No builder name specified.');
    }
```

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700724/angular-build-cannot-read-property-split-of-undefined

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip, I already checked that one and unfortunately doesn't work for me